# Manually Removing a Replicate Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, replication

I have a single domain environment on Active Directory, Windows Server 2003.  I created a replicate domain controller to put on a remote LAN connected via site-to-site vpn.  I shipped the server but now we have decided not to use it.

Instead of me travelling to where the secondary domain controller is and running DCPROMO on it, can I just manually remove it on my Primary Domain Controller?

Whats the best practices for this?  Also, the site for this replicate domain controller isn't even physically up, so I would want to remove the site as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the machine is online, I would recommend RDP'ing to it to run the DCPROMO.

Otherwise, the [Technet Article "Force Removal of a Domain Controller"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781245%28WS.10%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately the machine is not online.

Comment: @drpcken: @gWaldo linked to a Technet that covers forcing offline removal of a DC.

Comment: I can then remove the site correct? The site isn't even live yet.

Comment: Ok so I followed all those instructions and removed the offline DC. However it still shows up in my AD Sites and Services under both sites (my main domain site and the site where the offline DC was).  I want to remove the old site.  Can I just remove the server manually here by deleting it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

NTDSUtil will do this. It will remove all references to the DC from Active Directory. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498